# ¿Como solucionar error 405 (Method Not Allowed) al hacer update con fech ajax y laravel 10?

Tags: php, laravel, ajax

Estoy creando un crud con ajax anteriormente usaba javascript puro para el ajax donde no tenia problemas. Ahora eh decidido probar fetch creando una funcion para el envio por ajax. Cambie rutas probe otros metodos de envio y nada. Este es un resumen del codigo que uso

```
function fetchData(url, method, data = null) {
    const csrfToken = document
        .querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]')
        .getAttribute("content");

    const headers = {
        "X-CSRF-TOKEN": csrfToken,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    };

    const options = {
        method: method,
        headers: headers,
        // Si estás enviando datos, conviértelos a JSON
       // body: data ? JSON.stringify(data) : null,
    };

    return fetch(url, options)
        .then((response) => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
            }
            return response.json();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(
                "There was a problem with the fetch operation:",
                error
            );
        });
}

////funcion actualizar

function updateUser() {
    const form = document.getElementById("formEditUsers");
    if (form) {
        form.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            const id = document.getElementById("idEdit").value;
            // Define la URL de la solicitud
            const url = base_url + "/admin/usuarios/" + id;
            // Obtén los datos del formulario
            const formData = new FormData(form);
            // Llama a la función fetchData para hacer la solicitud
            fetchData(url, "POST", formData)
                .then((data) => {
                    console.log(data);
                    // Aquí puedes realizar acciones adicionales con los datos recibidos
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log("Error: " + error);
                });
        });
    }
}
```

estoy usando resource para generar las rutas del CRUD

```
Route::resource('/admin/usuarios', UsuariosController::class)->names('users');
```

mi controlador donde solo tengo esto para saber si estoy recibiendo los datos

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {

        echo 'viene al update';
    
    }
```

y finalmente mi form super basico para enviar los datos de actualizacion

```
<form id="formEditUsers" method="POST"  class="row g-3 needs-validation" novalidate>
    @csrf
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label for="names" class="form-label">Nombres</label>
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="idEdit" name="id">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="namesEdit" value="{{ old('name') }}"
            required>
        <div class="valid-feedback">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 footer-buttons-modals">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Guardar cambios</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

El error recibido es: `POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/usuarios/3 405 (Method Not Allowed)`
Realmente eh probado de todo pero no consigo hacer esto.

**Actualizacion**

Luego de seguir moviendo cosas eh visto que el problema pareciera estar en mi controlador en mi metodo update sucede que si uso el metodo asi funciona

```
  public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        echo 'viene';
    }
```

Pero yo lo eh estaba haciendo asi con un request personalizado

```
  public function update(UsersRequest $request, $id)
    {
        echo 'viene';
    }
```

Y en el request solo tengo esta regla

```
 public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required',
    }
```

Entonces realmente por que obtengo ese error 405 cuando en mi metodo uso un request personalizado.

Comment: El error 405 se da cuando la URL es correcta, pero no acepta el method (post,get,put,etc)

Comment: Tenes comentado `// body: data`, pero el body tiene que ir con los campos del formulario porque ahí están el `csrf_token` y el campo `_method`

Comment: Gracias pero al final me acabo de dar cuenta que el js no es el problema al parecer si no mi controller eh metido una actualizacion explicando mejor.

Comment: Necesitas un Spoofing ya que en Laravel  los HTML forms no soportan PUT, PATCH, o DELETE, [Referencia Laravel 10](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#form-method-spoofing)

Answer (score 0):

Un controller de tipo Resource tiene los métodos:

- index (lista los usuarios) debes responder con una vista.
- show (muestra un usuario) debes responder con una vista.
- edit (muestra el formulario para editar un usuario) debes responder con una vista.
- create (muestra el formulario para crear un usuario) debes responder con una vista.
- store (crea un nuevo usuario) debes responder con  una redirección a la ruta asociada a `show`
- update (actualiza un usuario)  debes responder con  una redirección a la ruta asociada a `show`
- delete (elimina un usuario)  debes responder con  una redirección a la ruta asociada a `index`

Para pegarle al método `create` la petición sería

```
POST /admin/usuarios
```

Para pegarle al método `update` la petición sería

```
PUT /admin/usuarios/{id}
```

Por la manera como funciona la inyección de dependencias en Laravel, si en tu método `update` pides una instancia del modelo de usuario en vez de simplemente el ID, ocurre un route-model-binding implícito.

Ahora bien, los formularios HTML no pueden enviar peticiones que no sean GET o POST. Para simular una petición PUT laravel pone un input de tipo hidden

```
  <input type="hidden" value="PUT" name="_method">
```

Para actualizar un usuario via `fetch` el método tiene que ser `PUT` o bien enviar en el body el valor de `_method` (que es PUT). Lo que definitivamente no funcionará es enviar una petición POST a la ruta `/admin/usuarios/{id}`.

¿Por qué te funcionó en algún momento llegar al método `update` si quitabas el route-model-binding? No sé, pero también me ha pasado. Usa los parámetros que sí te funcionan antes de ponerte a resolver eso otro, que es un problema secundario.